# Organizing Areas in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

Get ready for yet another elementary question from me...I think I have a grasp on the Area concept in a MVC site, but I would like to organize them even further, could I either move them to an external project (with controllers, views, scripts, styles) or create sub-folders within the Area folder?

Reason I'm asking is that I have tried to create a folder under Areas and called it Common, then created an area inside that folder and called it MyTest.  When I attempt to browse to `mysite.com/mytest`, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to go the *usual* way and use areas as a subfolder of the `Areas` ASP.NET root folder. The only reason why your URL would fail is that your `AreaRegistration` file is not properly registering your route. You can check out `Glimpse` as a way to debug routes or simply look at the files and try to figure it out your self. Keep in mind that ASP.NET automatically look for classes that inherit from `AreaRegistration` and use them to register routes that are specific to your area. If your routes seem to be configured properly, make sure your controllers are in namespaces that are visible to the route.

If you want to isolate the areas (with the controllers models and views) into separate projets, you should look into creating your own `VirtualPathProvider`, because that's the only way for your views to be located. However, they would have to be `Embedded Resource` and couldn't be debuuged. Your area, if located in a separate DLL, would be automatically registered and your controllers would be automatically found as long as the DLL is in the main application `Bin` folder.